# -Ywarn-unused-import triggering on play routes file

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, scalac

I want to be able to use `-Xfatal-warnings` and `-Ywarn-unused-import`, the problem is that the compiler is triggering an error on the file which contains the play routes for my application:

```
[error] /path/to/app/conf/routes: Unused import
[error] /path/to/app/conf/routes: Unused import
[error] /path/to/app/conf/routes:1: Unused import
[error] GET        /document/:id        my.app.controllers.MyController.getById(id: Int)
```

same goes for other routes.

Is it possible maybe to tell scalac to ignore a file?

Scala version is `2.11.8`.

Comment: What scala version? I contributed a fix for the warning related to implicit search, some time ago. I would try a sample project if you can do it. There's no mechanism to ignore a file, except that in 2.11 you can supply a reporter that does whatever it wants.

Comment: @som-snytt I"m using scala `2.11.8`, [here you can find an example project](https://github.com/EndeNeu/wron-warn-example), just needs to be compiled.

Comment: any update on the subject ?

Comment: The templates do indeed inject extra imports at route compile. It might be possible to exclude the route classes from scalac task and then use custom task to compile; or run a formatter that cleans up the imports; or make the route compiler smarter. I haven't tried yet.

Comment: @som-snytt I actually saw some imported being generated in the `Routes.scala` file but the compiler points directly to the `routes` file and I'm not sure why or if it matters. Regarding the formatter, scalariform doesn't support import optimization, maybe can be set in Intellij. Regarding scalac I don't even know were to start, googling didn't help either.

Comment: I've the exact same issue, Scala 2.11.8, Play 2.5.10. I ended up commenting out `warn-unused-import`. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't.

Answer (score 7):

I've come up with a working solution for Scala 2.13.7 (no need for any plugin) for Play 2.8.11. Take a look on those examples and adjust to your needs:

```scala
scalacOptions ++= Seq(
    "-Wconf:cat=unused-imports&site=.*views.html.*:s", // Silence import warnings in Play html files
    "-Wconf:cat=unused-imports&site=<empty>:s", // Silence import warnings on Play `routes` files
    "-Wconf:cat=unused-imports&site=router:s", // Silence import warnings on Play `routes` files
    "-Wconf:cat=unused-imports&site=v1:s", // Silence import warnings on Play `v1.routes` files
    "-Wconf:cat=unused-imports&site=v2:s", // Silence import warnings on Play `v2.routes` files
    "-Wconf:cat=unused-imports&site=views.v1:s", // Silence import warnings on Play `views.v1.routes` files
    "-Wconf:cat=deprecation&site=controllers\\.v1.*&origin=scala.util.Either.right:s", // Silence deprecations in generated Controller classes
    "-Wconf:cat=deprecation&site=.*v1.Routes.*&origin=scala.util.Either.right:s"
  ) // Silence deprecations in generated Controller classes
```

If you want to understand more, take a [look on this documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/2021/01/12/configuring-and-suppressing-warnings.html) and add verbose information on the compiler messages output

```scala
scalacOptions += "-Wconf:any:wv",
```

Pro tip: fail compilation of unused only within CI

```scala
scalacOptions ++= {
  // Mark unused errors as info for local development (due to -Werror usage)
  if (insideCI.value) Seq.empty else Seq("-Wconf:cat=unused:i")
},
```

Comment: In my case, I used the followings to silence html and routes related warnings: `"-Wconf:cat=unused-imports&src=.*routes.*:s"` and `"-Wconf:cat=unused-imports&src=.*html.*:s"`

Answer (score 5):

I just encountered the same problem with Scala 2.12 and Play 2.6 (which you're probably now using).

A Scala compiler plugin called Silencer sorts it out:
https://github.com/ghik/silencer

Add the following dependency into build.sbt:

```
val silencerVersion = "1.2.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    compilerPlugin("com.github.ghik" %% "silencer-plugin" % silencerVersion),
    "com.github.ghik" %% "silencer-lib" % silencerVersion % Provided
)
```

Then add (also in build.sbt):

```
scalacOptions += "-P:silencer:globalFilters=Unused import"
```

The text after the `globalFilters=` is a list of regex matches for compiler warnings to silence, can be comma-separated. You might need to tweak the regex for your own case, but I found the above example worked fine.

It does mean that it silences any "Unused import" warnings, but if you're in the habit of auto-formatting your code (`ctrl+alt+L` in Intellij), including tidying up unused imports, then it shouldn't cause a problem.

Comment: This looks promising, I will try it out in the next days!

Comment: This just suppresses all warnings for me

Comment: @Pavel Thanks for the feedback, I've updated the answer to correct the regex.

Comment: @MattStephens won't it suppress all "Unused import" warnings now? Anyway for me silencer-plugin with any globalFilters key just suppresses all warnings (I tried different regexps, different keys, different code), for sure there is a bug in silencer.

Comment: @Pavel yep that's correct, as I noted in the last paragraph. How much of a problem that might be probably depends on personal preference & whether your team habitually auto-tidies their imports. Can't really comment on silencer, as it worked fine over here; changing the regex I could switch it from working to not working, and back. Different Scala/JVM/sbt versions perhaps?

Answer (score 4):

A horrible "solution" could be to remove those unused imports after the routes are generated but before the compile task runs. Here's a sketch:

```
lazy val optimizeRoutesImports = taskKey[Unit]("Remove unused imports from generated routes sources.")

optimizeRoutesImports := {

  def removeUnusedImports(targetFiles: (File) => PathFinder, linesToRemove: Set[String], linesToReplace: Map[String, String]) = {
    val files = targetFiles(crossTarget.value).get
    files foreach { file =>
      val lines = sbt.IO.readLines(file)
      val updatedLines = lines map { line =>
        linesToReplace.getOrElse(line, line)
      } filterNot { line =>
        linesToRemove.contains(line.trim)
      }
      sbt.IO.writeLines(file, updatedLines, append = false)
    }
  }

  removeUnusedImports(
    _ / "routes" / "main" / "controllers" / "ReverseRoutes.scala",
    Set("import ReverseRouteContext.empty"),
    Map(
      "import play.api.mvc.{ QueryStringBindable, PathBindable, Call, JavascriptLiteral }" ->
        "import play.api.mvc.{ QueryStringBindable, PathBindable, Call }",
      "import play.core.routing.{ HandlerDef, ReverseRouteContext, queryString, dynamicString }" ->
        "import play.core.routing.{ ReverseRouteContext, queryString, dynamicString }"
    )
  )

  removeUnusedImports(
    _ / "routes" / "main" / "controllers" / "javascript" / "JavaScriptReverseRoutes.scala",
    Set(
      "import play.core.routing.{ HandlerDef, ReverseRouteContext, queryString, dynamicString }",
      "import ReverseRouteContext.empty"
    ),
    Map(
      "import play.api.mvc.{ QueryStringBindable, PathBindable, Call, JavascriptLiteral }" ->
        "import play.api.mvc.{ QueryStringBindable, PathBindable }"
    )
  )

  removeUnusedImports(
    _ / "routes" / "main" / "router" / "Routes.scala",
    Set("import play.core.j._"),
    Map())
}
```

You'll then want to sort out the task dependencies:

```
// Our optimize routes imports task depends on the routes task.
optimizeRoutesImports := (optimizeRoutesImports dependsOn (play.sbt.routes.RoutesKeys.routes in Compile)).value

// And compilation depends on the unused routes having been removed.
compile := ((compile in Compile) dependsOn optimizeRoutesImports).value
```

You'll also likely need to set `TwirlKeys.templateImports` to a conservative list before enabling `-Ywarn-unused-import`. Something like this, depending on what types are used in your views:

```
TwirlKeys.templateImports := Seq("play.api.mvc._", "play.api.i18n.Messages", "controllers.routes")
```

I also had to knock unused `TemplateMagic` imports out of Twirl templates (YMMV):

```
  removeUnusedImports(
    _ / "twirl" ** "*.template.scala",
    Set("import play.twirl.api.TemplateMagic._"),
    Map())
```

If you do that, make sure the task dependencies are set up appropriately.

This works for me. Scala 2.11.8, Play 2.5.10, both `-Xfatal-warnings` and `-Ywarn-unused-import` enabled. It's hideous, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option (possibly inferior to that of danielnixon)

I added the following to `build.sbt`:

```
import CustomGenerator._

import play.sbt.routes.RoutesKeys
RoutesKeys.routesImport := Seq.empty
routesGenerator := ModifiedInjectedRoutesGenerator
```

Then added this to `project/CustomGenerator.scala` (always top level `project/`):

```
object CustomGenerator {
  object ModifiedInjectedRoutesGenerator extends play.routes.compiler.RoutesGenerator {
    import play.routes.compiler._
    import play.routes.compiler.RoutesCompiler.RoutesCompilerTask

    def generate(task: RoutesCompilerTask, namespace: Option[String], rules: List[Rule]): Seq[(String, String)] = {
      play.routes.compiler.InjectedRoutesGenerator.generate(task, namespace, rules) map { case(key, value) =>
        var v = value
        if(key.endsWith("/ReverseRoutes.scala")) {
          v = v.replace("import ReverseRouteContext.empty", "implicit val empty = ReverseRouteContext(Map())")
          v = v.replace("import play.core.routing.{ HandlerDef, ReverseRouteContext, queryString, dynamicString }", "import play.core.routing.{ ReverseRouteContext, queryString }")
          v = v.replace("import play.api.mvc.{ QueryStringBindable, PathBindable, Call, JavascriptLiteral }", "import play.api.mvc.{ QueryStringBindable, Call }")
        }
        if(key.endsWith("migrations/ReverseRoutes.scala")) {
          v = v.replace("import play.api.mvc.{ QueryStringBindable, Call }", "import play.api.mvc.{ Call }")
          v = v.replace("import play.core.routing.{ ReverseRouteContext, queryString }", "import play.core.routing.{ ReverseRouteContext }")
        }
        if(key.endsWith("/JavaScriptReverseRoutes.scala")) {
          v = v.replace("import ReverseRouteContext.empty", "")
          v = v.replace("import play.api.mvc.{ QueryStringBindable, PathBindable, Call, JavascriptLiteral }", "import play.api.mvc.{ QueryStringBindable, JavascriptLiteral }")
          v = v.replace("import play.core.routing.{ HandlerDef, ReverseRouteContext, queryString, dynamicString }", "")
        }
        if(key.endsWith("migrations/javascript/JavaScriptReverseRoutes.scala")) {
          v = v.replace("import play.api.mvc.{ QueryStringBindable, JavascriptLiteral }", "")
        }
        if(key.endsWith("/Routes.scala")) {
          v = v.replace("import play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory._", "")
          v = v.replace("import play.core.j._", "")
          v = v.replace("import ReverseRouteContext.empty", "implicit val empty = ReverseRouteContext(Map())")
        }
        (key, v)
      }
    }

    def id: String = "injected+"
  }
}
```

Play sbt plugin generates routes code (can be seen under `target/scala-2.11/routes`). This code snippet removes or inlines all unused imports. You might need to tailor it for your routes.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem too. Basically Scala 2.12.13 or 2.13.x incorporates the Silencer code into their -Wconf compiler flag [see here](https://www.scala-lang.org/2021/01/12/configuring-and-suppressing-warnings.html).

Example:

```
scalacOptions += "-Wconf:cat=unused-imports:s"
```

It is possible to restrict this rule to certain source file eg routes ([see doc](https://www.scala-lang.org/2021/01/12/configuring-and-suppressing-warnings.html)) but I had no luck when I tried.

For previous versions of Scala, then you should use the Silencer plugin with:

```
scalacOptions += "-P:silencer:pathFilters=views;routes",
```